# Passing form Data to servlet using Extjs

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, extjs4

i'm new in ExtJS and Servlet.

I created a form with 2 fields usinf ExtJS :

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', 
{
    title: 'Personnal Data', 
    bodyPainting: 5, 
    width: 350, 
    region:'center',    
    url: 'save_form.php',

    items: 
    [{
        xtype: 'textfield', 
        fieldLabel: 'First Name ',
        name: 'firstName'
    },

    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name ',
        name: 'lastName'
    }], 

    buttons:
    [{
        text: 'Submit',  
        handler: function() 
        {
              var formData = this.up('form').getForm();         

        }
    }]
});
```

But i don't know how to pass the value of the two fields to a servlet, by clicking on the button. 
And how can i retrieve the data entered in the form, in the servlet ?

Thank you !

Comment: You need to learn how to make ajax calls form ExtJs. Gor getting started with, you can refer http://docs.sencha.com/core/manual/content/ajax.html

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax

Comment: hold on... you tagged this question with "java", but you are sending it to a PHP?

Comment: Sorry, just a mistake in my code. I actually use java servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default ExtJS Forms will send over the values in an "ajax" fashion and I believe it will be a "post". In your servlet (assuming you are posting to a servlet defined in your web.xml file) in your doPost (or doGet) methods, use the "request" variable in the method and do

```
 request.getParameter("firstName")
```

and

```
request.getParameter("lastName")
```

.

[Link to HttpServlet Definition (is the same for just about every java container).](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html)

Edit:

In your handler you need to add:

```
formData.submit();
```

Comment: Thank you. 

But what do i have to do in order to tell the app.js that i want to send the data in myservlet.java ?

Currently, it's like that :
{
   xtype: 'button', 
   text: 'save'
  }

Comment: Add handler to button which does the Ext.Ajax.request.. http://alvinalexander.com/javascript/sencha-touch-extjs-json-encode-post-examples  for an example

Comment: Hey... no problem... glad you were able to get it.